# Best practice: Should I note Gravatar is used on the website?

Tags: best-practices, users, comments, user-engagement, gravatar

I am going to implement a comment system on a website and I'm going to implement [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) as user's avatars. Since the form for posting comments doesn't have a field for uploading an image, nor does the website have an option to even register your account (you only post comments by providing your name and email), I am worried that some people might be confused as to how or why a custom image appears next to some comments and others are generic.

I haven't been able to find any relevant answers to this question, but I also never saw any other Gravatar using websites explicitly noting they use Gravatar. So I guess my question is why I never saw that?

I would like to put just a tiny note, like a disclaimer, below the comment form that would explain that the image next to your comment is your Gravatar, with a link to Gravatar's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the sites that I use mention Gravatar while inputting the comment. It would be useful and more colorful for your site to promote the Gravatar as this makes your site more rich.

So I would recommend you use a little disclaimer but heres another idea for you to explore in the name field you could have a temporary message until clicked like: Gravatar Supported, and then it clears that name when they click to enter the their, just a idea but there's no right or wrong answer on this question. Just go with whatever you think gives your users the best user experience.

Comment: Hey, can you just post a link or two to some of those websites? I just wanna see examples